# conditional header source based on server url path

Tags: php, url, conditional-statements

**Problem:** I want to load a custom header file for each content type (`$categoryId`) on my CMS.  For example, if the url is "/?action=archive&categoryId=1", I want it to include my "header_medicine.html" file.

I'm definitely a php noob, but I've tried to respect this forum and solve my question using the tips at  [this post about conditional code based on url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302559/conditional-code-based-on-url), but the archive page still loads from my 'else' condition.

Here's the code:

```
<?php $archive_url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

if ($archive_url['path'] == "/?action=archive&categoryId=1")
    include "header_medicine.html"; 

    elseif ($archive_url['path'] == "/?action=archive&categoryId=2")
    include "header_science.html"; 

    elseif ($archive_url['path'] == "/?action=archive&categoryId=3")
    include "header_other.html"; 

    else 
    include "header.html";
?>
```

Thanks for considering my question!

**Update: Solution**

For anyone who is interested, here is the working solution to the code problem I posted above (with simplified fileysystem syntax).  I didn't use the isset function that @Michael recommended in his code below.  Thanks to everyone who offered suggestions, I'm now one step closer to having a clue about php.

```
<?php switch ($_GET['categoryId']) {
    case 1:
    include "header_medicine.html";
    break;
    case 2:
    include "header_science.html";
    break;
    case 3:
    include "header_other.html";
    break;
    default:
    include "header.html";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Read about the GET super global.

Comment: Why not just use $_GET variable?

Comment: There is also a matter of changing categoryId, you should probably have a textual representation instead of a number, because for example, if you delete `categoryId=1` then header_medicine.html header will never appear. Also consider using `dirname(__FILE__)` on your code.

Answer (score 1):

You're taking the long way around something that is actually quite simple in PHP.  You only need to check the contents of `$_GET['categoryId']` via [the `$_GET[]` superglobal array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).  `parse_url()` and its cousin `parse_str()` will parse correctly parse out a URL, and in your case the part you would have wanted to look at was `$archive_url['query']`, but this is all unnecessary -- the information you need is in `$_GET`.

```
if (isset($_GET['categoryId']) {
// If this also depends on action=archive, use
// if (isset($_GET['categoryId']) && isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'archive')
  switch($_GET['categoryId']) {
    case 1:
      include('/header_medicine.html');
      break;
    case 2:
      include('/header_science.html');
      break;
    case 3:
      include('/header_other.html');
      break;
    default:
      include('templates/include/header.html');
  }
}
```

Now, I find it suspicious that you actually mean to include files like `/header_science.html`. `include()` calls filesystem paths, so unless your document root is also the server file root path `/`, these are probably not the correct inclusion paths.

You may instead be looking for something like

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/header_science.html');
```

Comment: Thank you so much @michael!!  I got it to work great using your suggestion.  Thanks for the concern about my include() filesystem calls, but I just simplified the syntax to present the question in a more straightforward way.

Answer (score 1):

You can access parameters in PHP via `$_GET`, `$_POST` and [others](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php). So `$_GET['action']` will give the action type archive and `$_GET['categoryId']` will give you 1.

So you can do something like:

```
<?php
  switch ($_GET['categoryId']) {
    case "1":
      include "/header_science.html"; 
      break;
    case "2":
      include "/header_other.html"; 
      break;
    default:
      include "templates/include/header.html";
  }
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Your example code will not work because `$archive_url['path']` will give you only the path `/`. Have a look at this example from php manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

```
<?php
  $url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';
  print_r(parse_url($url));
  echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
  [scheme] => http
  [host] => hostname
  [user] => username
  [pass] => password
  [path] => /path
  [query] => arg=value
  [fragment] => anchor
)
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanation about the parse function.  I'll definitely use that to solve an unrelated issue on my CMS

Answer (score 0):

Can you get the include path dynamically from your database?
It's not security safe to pass file locations through post/get.

Answer (score -1):

Use the $_GET array (OR $_REQUEST), it contains all parameters passed in url:

ex:

```
page.php?aaa=1&bbb=hello
```

you have:

```
 $_GET['aaa']
```

and

```
 $_GET['bbb']
```

containing their relative value