# Different url display different div - header.php

Tags: php, header

I may be asking a silly or stupid question. But, i am curious as i am beginner in php. I would like to ask whether this way is possible to happen.

Here goes the question:
I want something do like how wordpress do. But, i'm not going to use wordpress in this site. Like wordpress has the header.php in its path. And then, we can use wordpress php code to show or hide the content we like to display or hide as below.

Below is the php code i copied from Wordpress as an example:

```
<?php if (is_front_page()) { ?><?php } elseif (is_home() || is_single() || is_page() || is_archive() || is_404() || is_search()) { ?>
<?php
    /* We add some JavaScript to pages with the comment form
     * to support sites with threaded comments (when in use).
     */
    if ( is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) )
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );

    /* Always have wp_head() just before the closing </head>
     * tag of NCC, or you will break many plugins, which
     * generally use this hook to add elements to <head> such
     * as styles, scripts, and meta tags.
     */
    wp_head();
?>
<?php } ?>
```

Because, i going to create a simple website implemented with simple php coding. I am going to create a few pages -> `page1.php`, `page2.php`, `page3.php` and `header.php`. The `header.php` is to manage the head section of webpage(like how wordpress doing). Is it possible to get it done with simple php code?

Example:
When i visiting `page2.php`, the `header.php` will only display the content that i wanted to display.

Is it possible to change the `is_single()` to an `url`? Any suggestion? Or any other better solution can do this easier?

**Updated:**
`header.php`

```
<?php
function includeFile($file){
    if($file == "index.php"){

        Page Title for index.php

    }elseif($file == "page.php"){

        Page Title for page.php

    }elseif($file == "page1.php"){

        Page Title for page1.php

    }
}
?>
```

In my `index.php`

```
<?php session_start(); /* Starts the session */
if(!isset($_SESSION['UserData']['Username'])){
    header("location:login.php");
    exit;
}
?>
<?php include('functions.php'); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
<?php 
    require_once('header.php'); 
    includeFile(basename(__FILE__));
?>
</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.example.com/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body>
Content...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: take a look at this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982430/conditional-header-source-based-on-server-url-path, let me know if thats what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:**

Yes, you can certainly do that using [PHP magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) `__FILE__` and [basename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php).

**header.php**

```
function includeFile($file){
    if($file == "page1.php"){

        // include stuff for page1.php

    }elseif($file == "page2.php"){

        // include stuff for page2.php

    }elseif($file == "page3.php"){

        // include stuff for page3.php

    }
}
```

And in each one of your pages include the header file and call the function `includeFile()`, like this:

**page1.php**

```
<?php 
    require_once('header.php'); 
    includeFile(basename(__FILE__));
?>
```

**page2.php**

```
<?php 
    require_once('header.php'); 
    includeFile(basename(__FILE__));
?>
```

**page3.php**

```
<?php 
    require_once('header.php'); 
    includeFile(basename(__FILE__));
?>
```

Comment: Hey @Rajdeep Paul, thanks so much. It seems like what i am looking for. :)

Comment: I tried this code, but it doesn't work. Do i need to change anything in order to make it work?

Comment: Oh yes, I was wrong. `__FILE__` magic constant returns the name of the *included* file, not the *including* one. I have updated the above code snippet.

Comment: Hi Rajdeep Paul, i tried your updated code. But, it is still not working.

Comment: Please check if i have implemented the code correctly. Or i made some mistakes? I have updated the question.

Comment: It's working fine for me. Did you `echo` the page titles inside `if` clause in `header.php`?

Comment: Hi! yes. I didn't test properly. Now it works well. Thanks for your solutions! :)

Comment: Happy to hear. Please upvote and accept the answer. :)